# Possible to override CSS device-width in Awesomium?

Tags: css, mobile, awesomium

This is an awesomium-specific question. I am trying to make something that does screenshotting of websites for testing purposes. I need to be able to simulate mobile devices such as an iPhone or Android device. To this end, Awesomium is great but I would need to be able to set the device-width for the purposes of CSS media queries. Eg:

```
<link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="iphone.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Is this possible?

Comment: was about to ask the same question, did you haben to find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

Unfotunately Awesomium has a nasty bug. Still not fixed now on Awesomium 1.7.3.0.

If HTML tag has properties, page won't work with media queries:

```
<html lang="ru-RU">
```

But you remove properties, it should work just fine:

```
<html>
```

Comment: Thanks!

I was struggeling to get Awesomium to show the correct width for my bootstrap pages. Removing the attribute like you mentioned fixed the problem.